# Set an example for a @Failure annotation for Swaggo

Tags: go, swagger

I'm using Swaggo to do the documentation of my API and I'm strugling to add an example for the results of the requests (more precisely, Failure ones).

Here's my code of one path:

```
// @Summary Modification of a leave
// @Description Modification of a leave
// @Tags Leave
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  plain
// @Param modifLeaveRequest body ModifLeaveRequest true "Request to modify a leave"
// @Param leave_id path int true "Leave ID"
// @Success 200 {boolean} boolean "true"
// @Failure 400 {string} string "error in the fields"
// @Failure 401 {string} string "wrong login"
// @Failure 409 {string} string "the leave cannot be modified"
// @Failure 500 {string} string "an error occurred during the modification"
// @Router /leave/{leave_id} [put]
func handlerModificationLeave(c *gin.Context) {
   //Do some stuff
}
```

And here the result in the Swagger documentation:
[image: Http status]

What I want is to replace the `Example value` which is `string` by the actual error

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same question. In my case the error I'd like to display is a json encoding error, but.. is it even possible to know it at compile time?!

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure out the answer?

Comment: @vyakhir Unfortunately no, I just gave up at the time, and I didn't have the chance since to work with Swaggo :/

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax to define the Failure.

Here is an example:

```
//  @Failure    404 "Page not found"
```

Also, read the following to get an understanding about the syntax: https://github.com/swaggo/swag#api-operation